# Entropy of activation

Tags: reaction-mechanism

In [Price & Dwek](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198792816), I find a small section discussing entropy of activation for three examples

$$
1: \ce{Ce^{4+}} + \ce{EDTA}^{4-} \rightarrow (\ce{CeEDTA})\\
2, \text{S}_N\text{1 reaction}: \ce{AB} \rightarrow [A^+...B^-]^\ddagger\\
3, \text{S}_N\text{2 reaction}: \ce{AB} + \ce{C^-} \rightarrow [\ce{C...A...B}^-]^\ddagger
$$

What are the signs of the entropy of activtion $\Delta S ^\ddagger$ in 1-3?

For 1), the argument is that the formation of the complex releases water (because the complex is neutral), and so the entropy change is positive ($S_{final} > S_{initial}$ and $\Delta S = S_{final} - S_{initial}$).

For 3) (yes 3), the argument is that two molecules combine to form one, the solvation being less strongly affected compared to 1) because the charges are lower, and so $\Delta S < 0$ (two molecules have more degrees of translational freedom than one and on combination the average volume decreases).

Now for 2), I dont get it that $\Delta S > 0$. They only say

> "Separation of ions in transition state, hence a positive $\Delta S^\ddagger$."

Can somebody explain what this means? I would have guessed that the charges in the transition state require ordering of the solvation shell around the complex and so $S_{final} < S_{initial}$.

Comment: I think that you should just concentrate on your molecule in the transition state (not the bath). Then 2) is positive for the same reasons that 3) is negative. Your transition state in 2) is more loosely bound than the reactants, hence the energy difference between adjacent states in the reaction coordinate is smaller and more states are accessible under $k_B T$.

Comment: I'm probably not following what you mean by "adjacent states in the reaction coordinate". Could you elaborate  or rephrase this expression? Also, in 2), the transition state is still a coordinated complex, so still a single particle, therefore I didn't think it's the same argument as in 3).

Comment: Roughly speaking k$_B$T gives you the bar of energy accessible. With $S$ you count the number of states under that bar (there are fluctuations, as you are in the canonical ensemble). If the energy difference between two closest levels $\Delta E$ is smaller (and obviously you have to consider that $\Delta E$ is not necessarily constant) then you find more states that participate and sum up in $S$. When a potential is very loose (very anharmonic) you have smaller $\Delta E$. As a limit, the contribution of translations to $S$ per degree of freedom is always larger than that of vibrations.